the Question about using Flask and Vue to construct web app:uncaught runtime errors
I'm trying to use Flask and Vue to construct web app.
1.Here's my backend files named backend.py
from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/api/hello')
def hello():
    return jsonify({'message': 'Hello from Flask!'})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()

2.Here's my api files named api.js
import axios from 'axios';

const BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:5000/api';

export default {
  fetchHello() {
    return axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/hello`).then(response => response.data);
  }
};

3.Here's my web app's interface files named App.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="fetchHello">Fetch Hello</button>
    <p>{{ message }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import api from './api';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      message: ''
    };
  },
  methods: {
    fetchHello() {
      api.fetchHello().then(data => {
        this.message = data.message;
      });
    }
  }
};
</script>

4.then i have a interface like this,there is a button "Fetch hello"

I expect it would jump out 'Hello from Flask!", however there's an error:


You can check whether your server is running or not on port 5000, and can add some console statement to check whether the endpoint it being hit or not.

You're using Webpack ? Isn't there a boilerplate that works somewhere online?

Thanks! :)  i think it's a cross-domain problem,and I added "from flask_cors import CORS"ahead of my file named backend,py
